# Render html components changing its variables with javascript after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm getting a list of user's data using ajax. But after this ajax call, I have to render a html structure (like a datasheet) with many user's data to each user. My doubt is about how to "store" the HTML code in a functional and elegant way to keep my code readable and allow me insert the users data.

Creating a file with the component template and include it throught javascript is the best idea? If yes, how could I do this? If not, what's the best?

What I have:

Ajax call:

`

```
$("#list-users").click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url     : '/ajax/Users.php',
    type    : 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data    : data,
    success : function(users){
            users.forEach((user, index) => {
                //The problem is here. I'm looking for a way to
                //"store" the html component code to dont need put
                //the code inside a variable. 
                var complexHtml = '...<p>' + user.name + '</p>...';
                $('.list').append(complexHtml);
            })
    })
})
```

`

Comment: You could use a JavaScript templated string (delimited with backticks) and then set `innerHTML`.

Comment: Consider a templating engine like Mustache, Handlebars, Pug, etc, which allows you to define a reusable template elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> because it will make the success function very big and unreadable.

... are you looking for this ?
`

```
var myUSERS = {};
var myUsersLoaded = false;

$("#list-users").click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url     : '/ajax/Users.php',
      type    : 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data    : data,
      success : fctDo_Stuff_User 
    })
})

//...

function fctDo_Stuff_User(users) {
  users.forEach((user, index) => {

    var complexHtml = '...<p>' + user.name + '</p>...';
    $('.list').append(complexHtml);
})
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Using Vue/React/Angular can be a simple solution, because they do the rending job automatically for you.
Without using these frameworks, I usually do the following:

1. create a html template structure and style it invisible
2. use jquery clone to create
3. use jquery to set data
4. use jquery appendTo to display it.

Example codes are as below:

```
<div id="target"></div>

<div class="template-code" style="display:none">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="cls1"></div>
       <div class="cls2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
.... ajax success function (){
    var div = $(".template-code .container").clone();
    $(div).find(".cls1").html("data from ajax result");
    $(div).find(".cls2").html("data from ajax result");
    .... bind event as well if required ...
    $("#target").empty();
    $(div).appendTo("#target");

}
</script>
```

Hope this is helpful.